# Error $(...).tooltip is not a function in console

Tags: jquery, tooltip, jquery-tooltip

I'm getting an error saying `$(...).tooltip is not a function` in console.

This is my code

```
$('.selector').tooltip().mouseover(test);
```

Comment: can any one please help

Comment: Did you include any tooltip plugin? Look like nope

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include the jQuery and jQuery UI plugins into your code.  And make sure you use version 1.9 or higher.  In fact, the more up-to-date, the better.  Otherwise, if you have a version before 1.9, you won't be able to use this function.  Proof:

> version added: 1.9 (Source: **[API.jQueryUI.com: Tooltip Widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/)**.)

If you don't have a version of jQuery UI at version 1.9 or higher, you'll get the error: `tooltip() is not a function()`.